# Translating ANOVA from R to matlab

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, anova

I'm trying to translate a repeated measures ANOVA from R to matlab but can't get the WithinDesign/WithinModel parameters right.

Dataset has 7 measurements with 4 different settings and is provided in a table like this:

| Subject | Setting | Meas | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 12 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 23 |
| 1 | A | ... | .. |
| 1 | B | 1 | 34 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 26 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | A | 1 | 34 |
| 2 | A | 2 | 23 |
| 2 | A | ... | ... |
| 2 | B | 1 | 76 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 45 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Subject and Meas are given as.factor in R/categorical in matlab. With the measurements for the same subject and setting not being independent the used model and R code-line is:

```
res.aov <- aov(Value ~ Setting + Meas + Error(Subject/Meas), data=data)
```

Translating this to matlab I would go with something like

```
rm = fitrm(data, 'Value ~ Setting + Meas', 'WithinDesign', ????);
res_aov = ranova(rm, 'WithinModel', ????);
```

I tried a few different things to enter for the ???? gaps but it mostly didn't run at all or gave wrong results (including attempts with ChatGPT). Maybe I also need to format/provide my data in a different form.

Comment: Hello confusedius. In order to make this a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please add a sample dataset of your data in the form of a code block